# Why dipole correction does not work in VASP DFPT + phonopy calculation for a stable 2D material

Tags: vasp, phonons, phonopy, phonon-dispersion

Seems that DFPT method in VASP has many defects. It can't include vdw interaction. Now I found it also can't include dipole correction, which leads to a large negative frequency at $\Gamma$ point. I found this problem because two different phases of my structure has almost similar large negative frequency at $\Gamma$ point. Before this I've spent days tuning precision-related parameters.

So does anyone know the reason behind this?

Comment: +1 but can you please delete the screenshot and replace it with a `code block`, as discussed here: https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411/5?

Comment: I've done it. Thanks for your comment. I was not aware of this.

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly!

Answer (score 2):

I assume the problem has to do with the fact that the long-range Coulomb interaction looks different in 2D than it does in 3D. Dimensionality enters in Fourier space and yields a different asymptotic behavior for q --> 0. See Eq. (28) and (29) in
https://www.nature.com/articles/s41524-022-00920-6 .

Note that this answer is for phonopy. I am not familiar with the DFPT implementation in VASP and how long-range polar corrections are included there.